# Laravel4: check if the inserted email is in a proper format

Tags: forms, testing, laravel, laravel-4

In my app there is a little form with subscription to newsletter.
The form has just one field: email.

I want that when the entry is not in a proper email format, instead of throwing a laravel error: Address in mailbox given [fghfghfhf] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

I want to, more elegantly, give a validation error.

How can i define this rule?

Thanks!

EDIT:

This is my NewsletterUser model:

```
class NewsletterUser extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'newsletterusers';

protected $guarded = array();

public static $rules = array(

    'email' => 'required | email | unique:newsletterusers'

    );

 public static $messages = array(
        'email' => 'You already subscribed',
        'empty' => 'Insert the mail, please'
       );

}
```

And this is the subscription method in the Controller:

```
 public function subscription()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    $validation = Validator::make($input, NewsletterUser::$rules, NewsletterUser::$messages);

    if($validation->passes())
    {
       // subscription stuff
    }

    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation)->with('message','Insert the mail, please');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define a [custom error message](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-error-messages):

```
$messages = array(
    'email' => 'Address in mailbox given :attribute does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.',
);

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
How can i establish which message give depending on the error?

I publish my the old function in the Controller, and the edited Model.